# OOP: Should setters be private?

Tags: oop, class, setter

When writing getter/setters in classes, should the *setters* be **private** methods?

It might seem a bit redundant to have to write another method to set a variable but it seems like that might allow for a more maintainable code structure.

Comment: Aren't getters and setters supposed to be the only accessible parts from outside, and hence `public`? How would making another method make code more maintainable...

Comment: If your class was extended and you just used the getters/setters from the child class then you would still be able to control what goes into your class. It would just separate the structure from processing the data a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In General, I don't recommend "private" access for any member, maybe "protected". Usually, you or other programmer may require it in a descendant class.

**Long Boring Descriptive Answer**

Now, for accessors ("getters & setters"),  its also depends on the syntax and implementation of properties on the programming language.

For Example, C++, or Java, I consider not have "real properties", and accesors, maybe required to have the same scope as the properties. (Unless using a template for properties).

C# & Delphi (Lazarus) have properties implemented, but, I don't like the way C# declare the accesors.

There are cases, where you may want a property not to  be public, maybe "protected" or "package protected", and its accesors, the same access than the property.

I just work in some code in Object Pascal. Most properties where "public", and its accesors "protected", but, want to migrate that code to c++ or Java, so, I make the accesors "public", as well.

**Quick Short Answer**

Same access as the property, but, depends on the syntax of properties.

Answer (score 5):

Setter is a method that is suppose to allow modifying internal state of an object without exposing that object directly. We can later include validation or other logic inside setter.

If your setter is private, you are missing the point. It's like having a door in your house that is always closed and doesn't even allow opening. Also inside the class you can simply access the field directly, why would you use a setter there?

Of course the real question is: should we have setters at all? The typical class these days holds a bunch of fields, auto-generated getters/setters and no logic. This is hardly a class. It's just a structure with awkward way of accessing elements. But that's not what you are asking for.

Comment: I guess my thought is that if you owned the class in a multi-dev shop, then you could add primitive validation in your private setter and then other devs that might extend your class could make their methods that do things. It would just be enforcing base rules for validation.

Comment: Some setters *should* (for corresponding getters) be private. That is, just because one *can* create a getter/setter for all state,  doesn't mean one should .. I generally like to reduce "settable" state, preferring to use smaller immutable types and/or "actions".

Comment: If we are talking oop, encapsulation is the most important virtue, or the second most important virtue. Having public setters just throws encapsulation away.

Answer (score 1):

They should be public, if the intent is to allow them to be manipulated from an external object.  That is the point of POJO implementation.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)

If you're looking to implement some other pattern, perhaps looking at the docs on Java Access Modifiers should be your first stop (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Yeah I know Java kind of coined this idea but I'm not really working in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want setters/getters to be public, because that's what they are for: giving access to data, you don't want to give others direct access to because you don't want them to mess with your implementation dependent details - that's what encapsulation is about.

However there might be some cases where you want to restrict access to your data just to instances of the same class, but you still want to retain some control over the access to the data for whatever reason (bookkeeping, locking etc.) - in that case having private (or protected) setters/getters makes sense (from both code reuse and safety POV). However, you can't rely on the compiler to catch you doing something wrong then.

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I was thinking. What's an example of the compiler not being able to catch something wrong?

Comment: When you make private or protected setters/getters it's for a reason - you want even instances of the same class to use them instead of directly accessing the data. However, if they don't (because author of the piece of code - who can be someone else than the original implementer of the class - forgot about that), the compiler has no way to recognize that it actually is an error.

You can of course question whether the hierarchy is really correct in such case - it might indeed be a hint, that it's not necessarily optimal.